# Can I catch Windows notifications?

Tags: delphi, process, notifications

Can I somehow catch Windows notifications in RAD Studio? Such as browser notifications, or notifications from other application. Can I get the notification content?

UPDATE:
My program runs in the background, and when I receive a notification, for example a new email, my program brint to front and the notification body visible in the Memo.

Comment: You absolutely need to specify "notification". Do you mean window messages (`WM_something`)? Also, do you want to do this in a Delphi program at runtime, or in the IDE at design time? And what "content"? I'm afraid your Q is currently unanswerable.

Comment: I expect @Csanez means this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-notifications-overview

Comment: Further to my previous comment: you'd need to work out how to obtain, and use, this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Notifications.Management.UserNotificationListener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22621
There's nothing included in RAD Studio, so you'd need to work it out yourself, or have someone else do so

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to *Windows Notifications* usually shown in the *Action Center* sidebar, then Delphi provides a [TNotificationCenter](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Notification.TNotificationCenter) component which supports it. For a how-to see the documentation: [Using Notifications](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_Notifications)

Comment: Doesn't this only **send** notifications without being able to read all the others which are displayed by the OS?